# Jquery UI Tabs, Form Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, user-interface, tabs

I have a jQuery UI tabbed form, ex:

```
    <form>
  <div id="tabs"> 
   <ul>
                <li>Link to fragment 1</li>
                <li>Link to fragment 2</li>
                <li>Link to fragment 3</span></a></li>
                <li>Link to fragment 4</li>
                <li>Link to fragment 5</li>
   </ul>

<!-- Form Fields Step 1 -->
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel"> 
  Tab 1 Form Fields 
</div>          

<!-- Form Fields Step 2 -->
<div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
  Tab 2 Form Fields 
</div>

<!-- Form Fields Step 3 -->
<div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
  Tab 3 Form Fields
</div>
 <!-- Form Fields Step 4 -->
<div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
  Tab 2 Form Fields
</div>
<!-- Form Fields Step 5 -->
<div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
  Form Summary</div>
</div>
</form>
```

On submit, I would like validation that takes the user to the specific tab where the first error occurs.  Any help would be much appreciated.   -K

Comment: What kind of validation are you using? Server-side or client-side or both? If you're using server-side validation, what kind of data are you getting back when validation fails?

Comment: @Nolan did u get the answer for this question?If so please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

The lazy/easy way would be to use javascript to click the tab nav, for the tab that contains the error. Something like this...

psuedo code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    [validation here]
    on validate{
        $('input.error').closest('.tab_class').attr('id');
        var tab_num = get the tab number out of the id with substr
        $('#tab_nav_button_'+tab_num).click();   [javascript clicks the tab nav, showing the correct tab]
}

}
```

Comment: Why both simulating a click?  The tabs widget has a way to change tabs programmatically.

Comment: @Soviut - In that case should be even more straight forward!